# Using Facebook, Twitter or GMail to login my app

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, gmail

I'm developing an iOS 4 app with latest SDK and XCode 4.

I need that users login my app using his Facebook, Twitter or GMail account. But I also need to know the user that has login.

In other words, every user will have some specific data and I need to know which data is for a specific user. An example: there will be a lot of house, when a user buys a house, I need to know which user has bought that house.

When a user logs with Facebook, or Twitter or GMail, is there an ID associated with that account?

I need an ID to store in a Windows Azure server and I will use it to identify that user and retrieve all of his game data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I guess you're going to authenticate the users via OAuth on fb/twitter/google. Once you have the access token, make api calls with it to:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

for twitter,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

for google+ (assuming the oauth scope was google+: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`), and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

for facebook.

You'll get some id in the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I need an ID to store in a Windows Azure server and I will use it to identify that user and retrieve all of his game data.

Answer (score 0):

You can save their data after login in database or in file.
from where you can get the info that which user is login by which api and when like all info that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need an ID to store in a Windows Azure server and I will use it to identify that user and retrieve all of his game data.